# Custom Adapter getView() not being called using PullToRefresh library

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter, pull-to-refresh

Using Chris Banes' PullToRefresh library, the getView() method of my custom adapter is not being called. This code works fine *without* using his library and getView() is called.  I've been looking into this for a couple days now and cannot figure out what's wrong. **Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!**

**MyActivity.java**

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, data);
// the following toast displays the correct count
Toast.makeText("MyActivity", adapter.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    private ArrayList<Object> data;
    private LayoutInflater vi;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> data) {
        super(context, 0);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // not getting called
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason for your problem. Do you have same result when you use this adapter with android's standart ListView?

Comment: I have no problems when i use android's standard list view :(  .. only when i use the pull-to-refresh list view.  Also, this is working for a different activity in my app, but not for a few others i'm trying to implement. There's nothing different I'm doing in the activity where it's working too.

Answer (score 9):

Google IO 2013 has made many changes in ListView to optimize results. I had the similar problem as yours, my getView() function of custom adapter was not called.

According to new changes, if you are using "wrap_content" as layout_height of your view, getView() will be called only when user scrolls the list. So instead use "fill_parent" as layout_height of your view. It will solve your problem.

Use,

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

instead of using

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

@RTL

Your answer is not correct,I tried that but failed. Later I find the right solution.

We lacked **getCount()**

So we should add

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return yourArr.length;
}
```